# subscription and `Cannot read property ` error

Tags: angular

I am not able to understand that why I am getting `Cannot read property` error, when I get value of the query `group.query` as `{"id":40,"gid":1000,"group":"test","builtin":false,"sudo":false,"users":[47,44]}`

[image]

```
      checkbox_confirm_show(id: any){
    let user: any
    user = _.find(this.usr_lst[0], {id});
    this.ws.call('group.query', [[["id","=", user.group.id]]]).subscribe(res=>{
      this.group_users = res[0];
    })
    if(this.group_users.length === 1){
      return true
    };
    return false

  }
```

Comment: what is the output log of `this.group_users`?

Comment: `{"id":40,"gid":1000,"group":"test","builtin":false,"sudo":false,"users":[47,44]}`

Answer (score 0):

If `this.ws.call()` is returning an async observer, then your callback inside subscribe won't run until *after* your function has returned (much like the `then` on a Promise). So `this.group_users` isn't set when you try to access it.

You need to map the Observable to the value you want to check and then return the new Observable. Something like

`return this.ws.call('group.query', [[["id","=", user.group.id]]])
.map(res => res[0].length === 1)`

You can then either subscribe to `checkbox_confirm_show` or use an async pipe in your template.

Answer (score 0):

`this.group_users` is set asynchronously in a callback and this can occur after the `this.group_users.length` line is run. You may have to restructure your logic.

Answer (score 0):

@ryansilva is right.
Your

```
this.ws.call('group.query', [[["id","=", user.group.id]]]).subscribe(res=>{
      this.group_users = res[0];
    })
```

is an asyncronous function, you will set the value of this.group_users when that function returns, but your code `if(this.group_users.length === 1)` does not wait it to complete, so when it runs, group_user is still null.